# Body poking through the clothes

Tags: animation

When posing out the character during animation, parts of the body poke through the clothes..how can i get them to deform uniformly or together?

Comment: that may depend a lot of the clothes (shape, transparency, ...), so please add some pictures to your question. But the easiest way is to hide/remove masked parts of the body (if possible in your context). Are you using a cloth simulation here ?

Comment: I already masked some parts of tha body..no..am not using a cloth simulation...

Comment: Can you post an image of your model ? The solution may depend a lot of the clothes shape.